# loop through data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through the data in the div.

I'd like to get row by row data.

```html
<div id="result" runat=server>

  <div id="gvResult" class="RowGroup">
    <div class="Row RowBg" tabindex="99">
      <div class="Cell hidden-mobile hidden-tablet"></div>
      <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all">
        <p>PRM54</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all wb-keep-all">
        <p>YELEK</p>
      </div>

      <div class="Cell text-center tooltip-box tooltipstered">10,15 EU</div>

    </div>
    <div class="Row RowBgTwo" tabindex="99">
      <div class="Cell hidden-mobile hidden-tablet"></div>
      <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all">
        <p>PRMd54</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all wb-keep-all">
        <p>YELEsK</p>
      </div>

      <div class="Cell text-center tooltip-box tooltipstered">10,15 EU</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the results to come out like this.

first line in div and id="1"
 PRM54-YELEK-10.15EU

second line in div and id ="2"
 PRM54d4-YELEK-10.15EU
.
.
.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its just asking for finished code without any own effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am going to show you a sample solution (it's not fully implemented), you can try with this way.**

```js
var idCounter = 1;
$('.RowGroup').find('.Row').each(function(){
    let text = 'id: ' + idCounter + ' ';
    $(this).find('div').not(':empty').each(function(){
      text += $(this).text().trim() + '-';
    });
    idCounter++;
    console.log(text.substring(0,text.length-1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gvResult"  class="RowGroup">
            <div class="Row RowBg" tabindex="99">
                <div class="Cell hidden-mobile hidden-tablet"></div>
                <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all">
                    <p>PRM54</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all wb-keep-all">
                    <p>YELEK</p>
                </div>

                <div class="Cell text-center tooltip-box tooltipstered">10,15 EU</div>

            </div>
                <div class="Row RowBgTwo" tabindex="99">
                <div class="Cell hidden-mobile hidden-tablet"></div>
                <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all">
                    <p>PRMd54</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Cell ws-normal m-wb-break-all t-wb-break-all wb-keep-all">
                    <p>YELEsK</p>
                </div>

                <div class="Cell text-center tooltip-box tooltipstered">10,15 EU</div>

            </div>
 </div>
```

**Please don't hesitate to let me know if you need help in further.**

Comment: Thank you ur answer